# Build process for Xamarin.iOS when in Windows

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am doing a project in Xamarin for cross platforms, I am doing this on my Windows machine. What would be the best way for me to get the project to an iOS development in the future? Do i just open the project in an iOS environment then compile & deploy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need and iOS environment for you to build and compile the iOS project. If for deployment of the app itself to the appstore, you can check how to deploy to appstore since Apple has different set of rules when deploying, but if it's just for build/test yes, you can just use an iOS environment to deploy/test your app, just make sure that your VS on windows or Xcode/vs on mac is compatible. You just need to connect your windows Xamarin Agent to your Mac device IP address in order for them to communicate

[You can check this link for iOS deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes,your ios app compile/debug/run on ios simulator must use mac.You only need to configure the connection with MAC on visual studio.